# Websites detecting and blocking Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: url, selenium-chromedriver

I got a task to update a URL in a test (using Selenium, Java and Chromedriver) to a new URL.  The page is the same, just at a new location. This test worked fine with the old URL.

I brought up an instance of Chrome and verified I could access the URL.

Then I changed the URL, committed to git, and ran on our Jenkins machine and it failed.  The screenshot said "This site can’t be reached".  I told a co-worker that I think the URL must be wrong (though it worked on my desktop without Selenium).  He tried it and it loaded fine.  I tried it again from a regular Chrome window and it loaded fine.  I tried from Eclipse using Selenium and I got the message about the site could not be accessed.

So I ran Eclipse, stopped it right when Chrome came up but hadn't loaded a URL yet.  I manually entered the URL (from copy/paste) and got "This site cannot be accessed).  Then I brought up a regular Chrome window and pasted the URL in and it loaded fine.

I decided to look for differences.  So in my regular Chrome window it was "Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)".  I did the same on the version running under Chromedriver and got "Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)".  So the same.

I did a search for the latest Chromedriver.  It said for version 77 to please use 77.0.3865.40.  This was not what I was using.  So I downloaded the correct version and thought "surely this will fix it".  I verified it was 77.0.3865.40 coming up.  But, as you guessed it, I got the same problem after updating to the most compatible Chromedriver.

Some searches said that basically nothing would be able to tell, but there was one property that Chromedriver inserts.  I don't know whether this would be enough to block a session using Chromedriver?

The only thing I can think of is that we have iBoss and possibly iBoss is blocking it?  Either that or somehow the site is blocking it.

I would like to share the URL with you but I do not know whether that would be violating company policy. If I get permission, I will share the URLs.

by the way, the error is "ERR TUNNEL CONNECTION FAILED"

Answer (score -1):

Got some internal help to help fix some settings